# GitHub organization projects on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, github

I am one of the lead developers on a couple of packages on GitHub, but these are under GitHub organizations that I belong to rather than directly under my username. Is there an easy way for me to add these to my profile on careers.stackoverflow.com? Or is the only way to create a fork of those projects under my username on GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

Hi, we've added this to the GitHub import screen, please try it out. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried to add an organizational link but don't see any options on the GitHub import screen to add a reference. What should I be looking for?

Comment: Same here.  All I see are the public repos attached to my account.

Comment: @Dave +1 I have no such option either (and if I try to add them using the "other projects" link, it refuses and says to use the Github import instead [which makes sense]).

Comment: Same here as well. I have a single, embryonic project, but it's a group project. I want to link it, but can't yet. Soon, please!

Comment: Not there for me either! Can't be hard to implement...

Comment: NOTE: You need to make sure you are a "publicized" member of the organization on GitHub. You are not a Public member by default, it seems. Then the repos appear and you can add them. Cheers

Comment: @thaddeusmt Correct. The Github API won’t tell us about non-publicized members.

Comment: @MattSherman Note there seems to be a bug where URLs with a trailing slash don't get accepted (for example `https://github.com/TypeStrong/grunt-ts/`), but if the trailing slash is eliminated, it works.